# Reading a xml file in java

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I am making a cloud like project. Right now, what I'm going to have is that I get the downloadable folder for the user to install. When users drag and drop files into the folder they are added to an XML file that looks like this:

```
<File>
    <Name>application_for_employment2.doc</Name>
    <Type>doc</Type>
    <Size>144384</Size>
    <Path>\application_for_employment2.doc</Path>
    <Last_Mod>1365992658437</Last_Mod>
</File>
```

My questions:

- What is the best way to read this and get the info?
- Do I need to store this into my database?

Comment: ever hear of http://jsoup.org/ ?

Comment: "I am making a cloud like project" not much of a context to work with here. were is the folder drag&dropped? do they drag&drop the downloaded XML-File? There's no namespace on the XML, if you should ever need to have different version you're gonna have a bad time ;-), if your questions just concerns XML-Serialization i would recommend JAXB over XStream.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/source.html) for Parsing XML and JDBC connection to persist data.

```
        Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        List list = rootNode.getChildren("File");
```

For  [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/source.html) CODE Refer Exmaple [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/)

Answer (score 0):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) to get the XML into Beans and then [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) to put it into the database. Once your beans are set up and Hibernate is configured, the code is trivial:

```
Bean xml = (Bean)new XStream().fromXml(xmlStream);
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
xml.setId(session.save(xml));
session.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB (JSR-222) to read the XML into Java objects (an implementation is included in Java SE 6).

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

If you need to store the data to a database the. You could use the JPA APIs (JSR-327, with EclipseLink, Hibernate, OpenJPA, as the underlying implementation) to persist those same Java objects.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. I would suggest using StAX for reading the XML and JDBC to store info in database.

Comment: This should be a comment, include links to the mentioned APIs' and such.